# How do I receive email from google cloud platform bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We want to receive email automatically whenever new files are uploaded to the buckets from our clients, would it be possible?
Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by bucket? A google cloud storage bucket? Your clients can access it?

Comment: Hi, yes. a google cloud storage bucket. My clients can't access it directly, but if they upload a file elsewhere, the file will be added to storage bucket automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger a google cloud functions whenever there is some event in the bucket, in your case whenever a file is created. Then you can have your logic of sending an email in your google cloud functions.

For more info: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#functions-calling-storage-python